# How to order queryset by queryset in related model

Tags: python, django, orm

In the View, I need to order Projects so that the ones with Tickets assigned to the current user come first. I'm a bit confused about how to go about doing this. Is it possible with Django's ORM? Any help appreciated! thanks!

Models.py

```
class Project(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)

class Ticket(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="tickets")
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, related_name="created_tickets")
    assignees = RelatedSetField(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="tickets")
```

Comment: AFAIK RelatedSetField is not part of the standard models api. Where does that come from and what does that do?

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if any are assigned to the current user, display those first and pop them out of the queryset. Then display the rest of the queryset.

Pseudo Code:

```
tickets = Tickets.objects.all()
users_tickets = list()
for ticket in tickets:
    if current_user in ticket.assignees:
        users_tickets.append(ticket)
        tickets.pop(ticket)
tickets = users_tickets + tickets
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! yeah, I thought of that, but it feels like there must be something built in to Django's ORM that can handle it. I'm looking at Annotate..

Comment: You could exclude the projects from the queryset that don't have the current user assigned. Then append a query containing the rest of the projects.